# Url rewrite in wordpress using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to Rewrite wordpress url from

```
http://www.url.com/331 to 
http://www.url.com/?s=search&search=search&srch_property_id=331
```

Initially I have the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

and I need to keep it so I tried several things the closest i think is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^[0-9]+ /index.php?s=search&search=search&srch_property_id=$1 [NC,L] # Handle product 

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But i never got it to work.  I also need to make sure that only the url of the form http://www.url.com/POSTID where POSTID is numeric will be redirected using this rule.

Thank you very much for you time!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /index.php?s=search&search=search&srch_property_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

`$1` won't work I you don't have any parentheses. So either add those or use `$0`. I also added a `$` to the end so it won't match `/123whatever`.

Comment: I added RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /?s=search&search=search&srch_property_id=$1 [NC,L] between  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 and </IfModule>

in

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

I still get a 404 if i try http://www.maisons-a-vendre-quebec.com/331

But if i go on the home of my site and type 331 in the property id box in the search engine i will get to this property.

Is this due to something wordpress prevent me from doing?

Comment: Please add the code in this comment as an edit to your post, because I can't read this spaghetti of code and text.

Comment: I see you replace the `index.php?` with `/?`. This could cause your problem.

Comment: i tried both and it gives the same results...  RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /index.php?s=search&search=search&srch_property_id=$1 [NC,L]